# Spark SQL > Join (Shuffle) > Join query always failed because of "executor failed"

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark SQL (1.5.1) to run JOIN query in Spark Shell. The data contains extremely amount of rows, and the JOIN query never succeeded. Anyway, if I process with Hive SQL on Hive with the same data set, everything went fine. So probably there is something wrong with my configuration

From the console ouput, I found

"[Stage 2:=========================>                             (92 + 54) / 200]15/10/29 14:26:23 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on cn233.local: remote Rpc client disassociated"

On base of this Spark started 200 executors by default on base of the configuration spark.shuffle.partitions, and this definitely consumed all memory as I have a small cluster

So how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Client disassociated error occurs mostly in case of Spark executor running out of memory. You can try the following options

Increase the Executor memory

> --executor-memory 20g

You may also try to tune your memory overhead, if your application is using a lot of JVM memory.

> --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=5000

Try adjusting the akka framesize, (Default 100MB)

> --conf spark.akka.frameSize=1000

May be you may also want to try with smaller block size for the input data. This will increase the tasks, and each tasks will have lesser data to work with, This may prevent executor from running into OutOfMemory.

Comment: I recommend starting with akka frame size. I was certain my executor memory and executor memory Overhead where tuned properly, but as I was scaling my cluster up I started experiencing job errors. I knew that more executors should have completed the task faster, and did not want to increase my memory as that would decrease executors. Akka Frame Size seems to have fixed the issue.